# GetNamedItem() vs. index

Tags: c#, xml, xml-attribute, xmlattributecollection

Is there a difference between method GetNamedItem("test") and access by index in XmlAttributeCollection? Maybe in null handling or in something else?

```
xml_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("test").Value;
xml_node.Attributes["test"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XmlAttributeCollection.ItemOf Property (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b823yx9(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This property is a Microsoft extension to the Document Object Model (DOM). It is **equivalent** to calling [GetNamedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamednodemap.getnameditem(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I coudn't find it on msdn.